# Wordpress add_rewrite_rule redirects if page is startpage

Tags: wordpress, redirect, url-rewriting

I do a custom wordpress rewrite with the following code:

```
function add_rewrite_rules() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^mypath/([A-z0-9\-\_\,]+)/?$', 
        'index.php?page_id=2&tags=$matches[0]', 
        'top'
    );
}
add_action('init', 'add_rewrite_rules');
```

This works fine:
When I open `/mypath/tag1,tag2,tag3/` the page with the page_id==2 is shown, and GET parameter `tags` contains `tag1,tag2,tag3`.
The path stays `/mypath/tag1,tag2,tag3/`

**But there is one exception:**
When the page with the `page_id==2` is marked as the wordpress startpage, then he forgets everything and redirects to `/`

Wordpress seems to redirect to WP_HOME, if the page is the startpage, but I want it to stay on `/mypath/tag1,tag2,tag3/`, because I want to load my startpage and use the `tags` parameter in an angular script.

Does somebody have an idea how I can prevent this redirect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution by myself in this thread:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/184163/how-to-prevent-the-default-home-rewrite-to-a-static-page

Just disable canonical redirect for front page:

```
function disable_canonical_redirect_for_front_page( $redirect ) {
    if ( is_page() && $front_page = get_option( 'page_on_front' ) ) {
        if ( is_page( $front_page ) )
            $redirect = false;
    }

    return $redirect;
}
add_filter( 'redirect_canonical', 'disable_canonical_redirect_for_front_page' );
```